# Mixed content error with videojs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, video.js

I am using videojs in my react project. For that I am using the videojs script url 
http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.3.0/video.js. But when I am trying to run it on heroku then it gives me "Mised content" error like this:

[image]

I

Answer (score 0):

Error is self explanatory, you need to obtain the video.js library using HTTPS. Change you require, import or script tag or whatever you're using to HTTPS.

Comment: But does videojs supports https script tag?

Comment: VideoJS has nothing to do with HTTPS, it's a library that you need to serve over HTTPS. This will also be an issue for your videos.

Answer (score 0):

Use the protocol relative URL -- and also use the current version of Video.js. 5.3 is quite old now.

```
//vjs.zencdn.net/5.14/video.js
//vjs.zencdn.net/5.14/video-js.css
```

Or the minified versions:

```
//vjs.zencdn.net/5.14/video.min.js
//vjs.zencdn.net/5.14/video-js.min.css
```